# How to load images in pyglet using classes?

Tags: python, class, pyglet

Since my code is full of classes, the instance where I make a game window is under a class. Therefore, I don't have the line of code saying "@game_window.event". Is there a way to load images as sprites using classes?

EDIT:
I got this code from the pyglet documents. But it doesn't do anything when I run the game, no image is drawn on the screen.

```
brick_image = image.load('Brick.png')
brick_image.blit(100, 100,100)
```

Comment: please post relevant code

Answer (score 0):

```
class MySprite(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, texture=None, x=None, y=None):
        self.texture = pyglet.image.load(texture)
        super(MySprite, self).__init__(self.texture)

        self.scale = 1.0    
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x += x
        self.y += y

    def _draw(self):
        # Here you can do special draw scenarios
        # before you render your stuff, if you want.
        self.draw()
```

And in your main class, simply initate this with your image location `'Brick.png'` and in your main class and call `._draw()` on that handle in your rendering function, whatever that is *(you're lacking a whole lot to go on here so i assumed a couple of things)*.